# Python gevent asynchronous

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, gevent

When I use gevent and it's still synchronous and run time doesn't decrease.

Here is my script:

```
def fun(i):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['./main', 'data.txt'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    err = p.communicate()[1]
    p.wait()

def synchronous():
    for i in range(1,10):
        fun(i)

def asynchronous():
    threads = [gevent.spawn(fun, i) for i in xrange(10)]
    gevent.joinall(threads)
```

By comparing `%timeit synchronous()` and `%timeit asynchronous()`, there is little change. And the 'main' is the compiled c++ file and the 'data.txt' is the input file for 'main'.

I guess the problem is that I use subprocess to call a external routine, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Try using `pool.map` something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments

Comment: @lennard It seems work. Thanks a lot. But what's the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

p.wait()

This is making your code synchronous.